# How can I improve this NONCE library for PHP?

Tags: php, security

This is the first time I've worked with nonces, so I downloaded the script from http://fullthrottledevelopment.com/php-nonce-library. I did not like the code, especially because there's a chance of a legitimate request being treated as invalid because the function works in intervals of a defined amount of time (default is 300 seconds).

For example, we could be 299 seconds into the 300 seconds when the nonce is generated, so the nonce would only work for 1 second.

I modified the library into the following functions. What I did was check for the current interval and the previous interval by using `nonce_create(time()-NONCE_DURATION)==$nonce`. Are there ways to further improve the functions?:

```
define( 'NONCE_UNIQUE_KEY' , '123123' );
define( 'NONCE_DURATION' , 300 );

function nonce_create($time=false){
    if(!$time)
        $time=time();
    $i=ceil($time/(NONCE_DURATION));
    return substr(md5($i.NONCE_UNIQUE_KEY),-12,10);
}

function nonce_is_valid($nonce){
    if (nonce_create()==$nonce || nonce_create(time()-NONCE_DURATION)==$nonce)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Also, I have two questions regarding the original library:

1. Why isn't `NONCE_UNIQUE_KEY` used? Did the author simply forget?
2. Why does the author divide by two here: `$i = ceil( time() / ( FT_NONCE_DURATION / 2 ) );`, it only works for half the time then (I tried it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces a Nonce,  however it is not a cryptographic nonce.  The value that this library produces **must never** be used for security because it is heavily dependent on the use of time.   The attacker knows the current time,  and knows your server time because its in the http response header. Also md5()'s prng output isn't as random as it should be. There are many known vulnerabilities against md5, and it should **never** be used for security.  Also 10 bytes of base 16 pretty small, 16 bytes of base256 would be ideal.

If you need a unique value that is reasonably hard to guess then this will work in most cases:

`sha1(uniqeid(mt_rand(),true));`

However,  this is less than ideal.  the output is base16 which is very wasteful of space.  uniqeid() still uses time,  however there are other sources of entropy in the resulting value.

**By far the best** source of entropy for a web application is `/dev/urandom` and use `fopen()` to access it and read out 16 bytes of the base256 contents.  /dev/urandom is an entropy store that gathers sources of randomness from the operation system,  its hardware,  and the behavior of all applications on the system.

Comment: I don't see how creating a sha1 hash of the output of uniqid() makes it more secure / random. `output is base16 which is very wasteful of space`: base_convert(uniqid(mt_rand(),true), 36); - still not as compact as it might be, but approx half the size

Comment: @symcbean good question,  actually the call to sha1 is obscure the timestamp.  If you know when the nonce was created,  then it isn't as strong.  That being said you should never use `uniqid()`,  there are much much much much better alternatives,  such as an entropy store like /dev/urandom.

Comment: Just for the use as a nonce, I would not recommend to ask for entropy in `/dev/urandom`, because you just don't net such strong entropy for a simple nonce. Just use one-time nonces, bound to sessions. Unless you have an intercepted HTTP connection, an attacker will not be able attack your system.

Comment: @apfelbox this post has a security tag.  We should assume this is a cryptographic nonce,  and there for must be a very random number.

Comment: Sure, but why would you want to secure your nonce with cryptographic strength? What is not enough with just using one-time nonces, created with a default hashing function (sha1, for example) with a pepper? Nonces are just for preventing CSRF, not for securing your complete application (you should just use HTTPS for that).

Comment: @apfelbox the value produced by the library above is not acquitted for preventing CSRF.  The exact time is known to the attacker and there for this value is trivial to guess,  bruteforce is not required.  Also Bruteforcing CSRF is a very easy attack to carry out.  Your comments scare me, this code is very insecure.

Comment: I did not say, that the code posted above is secure, i just said that I think, that the following is enough: create a nonce using something like this: `$nonce = hash("sha256", uniqid(PRETTY_LONG_SALT, true));`. Store this nonce in the session (not a cookie), and send it to the form of the user. Also (if necessary) secure transportation using HTTPS. The user now needs to send the nonce with the next request (where it is checked). With it's response, a new one-time nonce is created. No need for cryptographically secure nonces, this is already enough.

Comment: @apfelbox  if you are going to do something,  it should be done correctly. /dev/urandom is free.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14775/discussion-between-apfelbox-and-rook)

Comment: Using a secret salt can improve the security of the nonce drastically.